# elseif onclick function won't show

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to output answers from clicking on buttons. Problem is, it will only do this for the if statement (first button), not the else ifs (2nd and 3rd buttons). What am I doing wrong?

```
<body>
<button id="button1" type="button" name="button">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" name="button">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button" name="button">Button 3</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");

function message() {

 if (button1.onclick) {
   console.log("fere");
 }

 else if(button2.onclick) {
   console.log("33.");
 }

 else if (button3.onclick) {
   console.log("hiii");
 }
 }


button1.onclick = message;
button2.onclick = message;
button3.onclick = message;
```

I expect these outputs after clicking once on every button:

fere
33
hiii

Comment: `if (button1.onclick)` is checking if element has onclick event. I think you want not this behavior. Check current clicked element ID instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use onclick attribute in button (in similar way like in angular/vue template)

```js
function message(n) {

     if (n==1) {
         console.log("fere");
     }

     else if(n==2) {
         console.log("33.");
     }

     else if (n==3) {
         console.log("hiii");
     }
 }
```

```html
<button id="button1" type="button" onclick="message(1)" name="button">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" onclick="message(2)" name="button">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button" onclick="message(3)" name="button">Button 3</button>
```

Comment: Just beat me to it ;-)

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Didn't know we could use arguments inside HTML strings. But okay, now I do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible to check against a method, usually in these cases it is common to verify against an id or some unique identifier, please try the following implementation

```js
const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
const button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
const button3 = document.getElementById('button3');

function handleButtonClick(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const id = target.id;

    if (id === 'button1') {
        console.log('fere');

        return;
    }

    if (id === 'button2') {
        console.log('33.');

        return;
    }

    if (id === 'button3') {
        console.log("hiii");

        return;
    }
}

button1.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick, true);
button2.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick, true);
button3.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick, true);
```

```html
<button id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3">Button 3</button>
```